# Problem with pow giving me an infinite answer

Tags: c++, pow

I'm trying to compute a discount factor given a rate and the number of payments to be made per year.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    uint32_t due_dates_per_year = 2;
    double t = 1;
    double rate = 0.05;
    double df = pow(1 + rate / due_dates_per_year, -due_dates_per_year * t);
    cout << df;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "inf" but it should be a little less than 1.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: In your real program, will the value of `t` be read from somewhere else, or will it always be `1`? If it will always be `1` then why use it at all, since any multiplication with `1` is kind of meaningless.

Comment: I was trying to make the example as short as possible. t is for time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the exponent (*i.e.* the second parameter) of `std::pow`. The expression

```
-due_dates_per_year * t
```

is *grouped* as `(-due_dates_per_year) * t` (that's how the C++ *grammar* parses the expression). The unary negation of the `unsigned` type produces a large (and also `unsigned`) number which explains the result.

Other than using a `signed` type for `due_dates_per_year`, the rearrangement

```
double df = std::pow(1 + rate / due_dates_per_year, -t * due_dates_per_year);
```

is a fix.

Comment: You should always used signed integers, unless you know you'll need to use the 32nd or 64th bit.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Yes, I think that's good advice here, although `unsigned` types don't make your program vulnerable to overflow cf. their `signed` cousins.

Comment: @Jeffrey • The exceptions to that advice (which I consider good general advice & endorse) are:  use unsigned integers when doing bit twiddling or other sorts of bit manipulation, including bit flags (or consider `std::bitset`); use `std::size_t` for indexes.